# Как заполнить базу случайным количеством комментариев к каждой статье в laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel-8

Для тестов заполняю базу при помощи сидов и фабрики.

Есть две связанные таблицы. Статьи и комментарии (has many).

При заполнении, указываю что мне нужно 20 статей и по 3 комментария к каждой статье.

Как реализовать, что бы к каждой статье добавлялось случайное количество комментариев (0,3) ?

```
Article::factory()
    ->has(Comment::factory()
        ->count(3)
    )
    ->count(20)
    ->create();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Article::factory()
->has(Comment::factory()
    ->count(rand(0, 3))
)
->count(20)
->create();
```

Не помню, можно ли передавать 0 в count. Если не получится, всегда можно добавлять дочерние модели в цикле

Comment: Наверное не совсем точно изъяснился. При таком способе выберется одно значение и будет использоваться (тоесть у всех 20 статей будет 0,1,2 или 3 комментария). Мне хотелось бы, что бы у каждой статьи было разное количество комментариев

Comment: @Gagablik Тогда только в цикле https://pastebin.com/K9XX1zLN